# Google App Engine PHP fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) doesn't work

Tags: php, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-sql

I've deployed a project on Google App Engine that returns Json Object on call to the url. 
I've use this code

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to return results that will only use column name as the key to retrieve the value from when parsing in the app.

However on deployment to the app engine when called to the same url the results returned use numbered index as well as column name as key as if this code was called

```
//Without setting the PDO::FETCH_ASSOC fetch style which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH
 fetchAll();
```

The project deployed works on the local development engine as expected however when deployed onto Google App Engine the above results was obtained.

**UPDATE 1**

My Google App Engine was configured to connect to bitbucket so whenever I have any changes in the code I'll push it to bitbucket and as far as I know the App engine code will be updated automatically and it does I've checked it.But the results I got was not what I expected when GAE gets the code from bitbucket.

However, when I chose to deploy my code manually from Google App Engine launcher everything just seems to work fine. I got what I wanted when the project was deployed onto GAE.

I have lots of unexpected results when configuring bitbucket to GAE (certain section of switch code won't run). But for now I'll stick to using Google App Engine launcher to deploy my code until a possible explanation arrives.

**UPDATE 2**

When debugging live on GAE, it seems to me that the newly added code through bitbucket push to deploy is not there at all even though I can see the code added already on the source code tab on the GAE console. For example, I added a new switch condition, however when running the and providing the correct argument that fits the newly added condition the code does not execute at all as if its not there. This wasn't true as I check the source code on the GAE console.

**SMALL SIDE NOTE**

Before using bitbucket I was using google app engine launcher to deploy my project. I'm not sure if this is the reason why the bitbucket project was not able to overwrite my old project that I deployed using Google App Engine Launcher.
I'll answer my own question if I figure out the solution.

**CONFIRMED ISSUE**

I can confirm that my bitbucket code did not replace the code of the project where I deploy using Google App Engine Launcher. I'm not sure what's the issue as on the browse code section in the GAE Admin Console I can clearly see the new code. However when running, the code running was the old one.

Comment: please edit your question so that it includes: What exactly isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler here you go.

Comment: ah, so your actual problem is that the 'behaviour' of the method is wrong?

Comment: Yes. I've set the intended behaviour to the code. It works as expected on my local machine however when deployed onto GAE the results are not the same as those I've seen on my local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the step to set up Jenkins which is needed for push to deploy to function. However the supported language does not include PHP so I can't do much about it.